# NodeJS Express JS Web App - How to roll out new features only for a subset of users?

Tags: node.js, express, access-control

We have a fairly widely used Node + Express Web App, for which we are enabling a new major feature. Because we don't know what the exact impact would be, we want to roll out this feature only to a subset of users and seek feedback before launching it completely. I see there are multiple ways of doing this:

- Use a flag in the User object to see if this feature should show for the user
- Roll out the feature for only a geography

I have seen major websites do this. Can anybody shed some light on how this is normally done?

Comment: There are couple libraries that can help. I'm currently using `fflip`, which does the job